# How to add item to the list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

Here  I have `selectedFiles` which have all the multiple file that I have selected in my `<InputFile class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" OnChange="OnInputFileChange" multiple ></InputFile>`.
What I am trying to do is to save all the file name in list `fileList`.
But the problem is that my list only contains the last file that I have selected.
Below is my code

```
IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles;
    public void postPerson()
    {
        foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
        {
            List<PersonFileUpload> fileList = new List<PersonFileUpload>()
            {
                new PersonFileUpload(){UploadedFileName = file.Name}
            };
        }
    }
```

```
public void OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedFiles = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
 public List<PersonFileUpload> PostPerson(IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> selectedFiles)
  {
       var fileList = new List<PersonFileUpload>()

        foreach (var file in selectedFiles)
        {
            
             fileList.Add( new PersonFileUpload{ UploadedFileName = file.Name})
            
        }

    return fileList;
 }
```